# File Upload JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, http, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I am going to create a Restful Web API for our client. I am new to Restful services. We are decided to use JSON as the format. 
There is a requirement that uploading some documents to the server. How we can make it possible. What I want to do in server side for this. How to give instructions to the Users of the service to the format of JSON or request.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the example of an image. 
You can load up the image to a canvas, then pull out the data url from the canvas and use that in your json that you send to the server. Regarding other document types I would have to investigate further. This technique does work

```html
         <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
        <canvas id="test">
        </canvas>
        <img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtLDZ.jpg"/>
        
        <script>
        window.onload=function(){
        var can=document.getElementById("test");
        var context=can.getContext("2d");
        var img=document.getElementById("image");
        context.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 150, 150);
        var dataUrl=can.toDataUrl();
        console.log(dataUrl);
        };
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would possibly take these two approaches-

- Use JSON in the url for any non-binary data.
- Use multipart form for uploading your document.